# why is this language regular?(complicated)

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-language

I am trying to understand why is the following language comprised of two languages $L_1$, $L_2$($L_1$, $L_2$ are regular) is a regular language:

$L_1$, $L_2$ are languages over the same $\Sigma$. $$L^\frown = \{ w\in \Sigma^* | w=u\sigma_1\mu_1...\sigma_n\mu_nv\}$$ where

- $u,v \in \Sigma^*$
- $0\leq n$, for every i($1\leq i \leq n$): $\sigma_i,\mu_i \in \Sigma$
- $\sigma_1...\sigma_n \in L_1$
- $\mu_1...\mu_n \in L_2$

Why is $L^\frown$ regular?

i don't understand the u,v in the beginning and end of word w.

if it didn't include u,v, i would've built an automaton (finite) that accepts $L^\frown$. so basically, this is the automaton i would've used without u,v:

$$A = (\Sigma, Q_1 x Q_2 x {1,2},(q_{01},q_{02},2),F_1 x F_2 x{2}, \delta)$$ and $\epsilon \in L$ iff epsilon is in both languages($L_1, L_2$)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you also assume that there is an automaton for $L_1, L_2$. You should write that they are regular.

Comment: Consider languages over $\Sigma$. If you have any regular Language $L$ (and thus an automaton for that language) and now a language $L' = \{ uw \}$ with $u \in \Sigma^*, w \in L$ then you can always construct an (nondeterministic) automaton for $L'$ which uses the automaton for $L'$ but adds an extra state as start state. In this extra state you can either stay or move to the old start state for all inputs. A similar thing can also be done for the suffix $v$.

Comment: edited the question, and could you elaborate a bit more? would really like to see how it can be implemented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider languages over the alphabet $\Sigma$. Assume that we have a regular language $L$ and an automaton $A = ( \Sigma, Q, q_0, F, \delta )$ that accepts $L$. Now consider the language $L' = \{ uw | u \in \Sigma^*, w \in L' \}$. The following nondeterministic automaton accepts $L'$: $A' = (\Sigma, Q \cup q', q', F, \delta \cup \{ (q', a) \rightarrow \{ q' q_0 \} | a\in \Sigma\} )$. Why does this work. Well consider any word $uw, u \in \Sigma^*, w \in L'$: Then there is an execution of the word on $A'$ where we first do $|u| - 1$ transitions from $q'$ to $q'$ and then one transition to $q_0$. From there on we are left with $w$ and we are in $q_0$ and thus we accept $\iff$ $w \in L$.
Consider any word that is not in $L'$: In order to not belong to $L'$ the word cannot have a suffix which is in $L$. But by definition of our automaton it only accepts words which have a suffix which is in $L$.

Hope this helps. For the case of the suffix $v$ you can replace all accepting states by a new accepting state and then introduce "edges" from all previous accepting states to that new accepting state. In that new accepting state you add an "edge" to itself for all $a \in \Sigma$.

Edit: I'm sorry it is not entirely correct what I wrote. For the empty prefix this construction does not work. You would have to allow zero transitions in order to make it work. Otherwise you could it without the new state $q'$ and just introduce a loop at $q_0$.

Comment: i did not understand the last part: for the suffix v, for A', should i do another addition to $\delta$ as if,$ L''={wv|w\inL'\,v\in\Sigma*}$ and then the final automaton would be $A'\:=\:\left(\Sigma ,\:Q\:\cup \:q',\:q',\:F,\:\delta \:\cup \:\left\{\left(q′,a\right)→q′,q0|a∈Σ\right\}\:\cup \left\{\left(q′,q_0\right)→q′,b|b∈Σ\:|\:\:\right\}\:\right)$ ?

Comment: what would be the final automaton?

Comment: Let $F$ be the set of accepting states of $A$. Then for $A''$ you should have a new accepting state $F'' = F \cup q''$ and all previous accepting states (meaning all states in $F$) should have a transition to $q''$ i.e. $\delta'' = \delta \cup \{ (q, a) \rightarrow q'' | a \in \Sigma, q \in F\} \cup \{ (q'', a) \rightarrow q'', a \in \Sigma\}$. The last union is for transitions from $q''$ to itself.

Comment: Note that I made a mistake in my answer and added an edit.